# Intel graphics problem 14.04.02

Tags: xubuntu, dell, intel-graphics

I have problem with my new Dell E7450, when I start Xubuntu 14.04.02 LTS it hangs up at login screen. It looks like this:

[image]

Elements are partly black and unreadable.

But when I ran it in recovery mode it runs without problems. 
I've found this topic: https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194
And installed intel graphics for linux installer but said:

> You don’t seem to have an Intel i915 chipset so no updates are needed

Here's some debug info:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

and:

```
$ modinfo i915 | head
    filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
    license:        GPL and additional rights
    description:    Intel Graphics
    author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
    license:        GPL and additional rights
    srcversion:     C6C6D0B5224D5DF3DCE1AE6
    alias:          pci:v00008086d00000155sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00008086d00000157sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F33sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F32sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
```

Please help.

Comment: I also have similar issues with a Dell E7450 but with regular Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other Desktops such as Kubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, as well or just with Xubuntu?